# React - not repeat a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react component for a dropdown:

```
var UIDropdown = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            isOpen: false
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        if (this.props.isOpen) {
            return (
                <div className="dropdown">
                     <ul className="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown tm-svg-center">
                        {this.props.mapOpacityValues.map(function (list, i) {
                            return (
                                <li onClick={this.props.opacityThermatic.bind(this, list) } key={"list" + i}><a href="javascript:void(0)">{`${list * 100}%`}</a></li>
                            );
                        }, this) }
                         </ul>
                    </div>
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

I'm looping through some data which outputs some list items, but I have a number for different data items.

How can I add the following in the component without repeating the dropdown component code:

```
   {this.props.mapOpacityValues.map(function (list, i) {
                                return (
                                    <li onClick={this.props.opacityThermatic.bind(this, list) } key={"list" + i}><a href="javascript:void(0)">{`${list * 100}%`}</a></li>
                                );
                            }, this) }
```

Example but with a single dropdown component
https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/ddLdg84s/

Comment: can you tell what different data items. fiddle is not working.

Comment: what do you mean with " I have a number for different data"? Is it that number the number in this part `${list * 100}%` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to reuse your `Dropdown` component

Then do something like this

**DropdownItems component**

```
var DropdownItems = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
           <ul className="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown tm-svg-center">
               {this.props.mapOpacityValues.map(function (list, i) {
                   return (
                      <li onClick={this.props.opacityThermatic.bind(this, list) } key={"list" + i}><a href="javascript:void(0)">{`${list * 100}%`}</a></li>
                   );
                   }, this) 
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
});
```

**UIDropdown component**

```
var UIDropdown = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            isOpen: false
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        if (this.props.isOpen) {
            return (
                <div className="dropdown">
                    {this.props.children} 
                </div>
            );
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Then you can create any number `UIDropdowns` like

```
<UIDropdown>
    <DropdownItems mapOpacityValues={someData} opacityThermatic={someFunction}>
</UIDropdown>
```

Here you need to repeat neither `dropdown` nor `li` items. You just resue them in your implementation.